# meet Error when fread a text file (Internal error: invalid head position)

Tags: r, linux, data.table, fread

When I use data.table::fread function in linux to read a plain text file, got an error:

```
Error in fread("file") :
  Internal error: invalid head position. jump=0, headPos=0x7fc4f2b9692e, thisJumpStart=0x7fc4f2a9807a, sof=0x7fc4f2a98000
```

But if I use fread in windows, it can read.

The both version of data.table are same: data.table 1.14.0

Any one know why? how to fix the problem in linux?

Thanks!

linux R session info:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /data/dermatogenomics4/software/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.10.dev.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "plain text file"? What exactly is in your data? Does it contain delimited/columnar data? Have you compared files sizes or MD5 checksums on the file to guarantee it's the exact same input data? Is the file compressed?

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4899

Comment: "plain text file": here the file is csv format file, seperated by ",".
I have checked and the MD5 are same in linux and windows.

Comment: And it is strange that if I head the file (top 6 rows) and export to a new file, it can be fread.

Comment: Is it a large file? How did you install data.table; did you compile from source? It may be better to post the issue to the data.table github issues page: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues. But they will probably need a reproducible example in order to debug.

Comment: Very good comments from @MrFlick, thanks.

Comment: Year, the file is large, about 600M. So it is impracticable to make a reproducible example. The data.table is intalled in R: install.packages(). I find this may related to the R software installed in the Linux. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: I have re-installed R 4.1.0 in the linux server, and solved the problem.